# Отправка почты через сайт

Tags: ubuntu, email, sendmail

Здравствуйте. Не работает отправка через сайт на VPS. (Ubuntu + Apache).
Подключена услуга Mail.ru для бизнеса (почта вида mail@mydomain.ru).

Вот текущие настройки:

**/etc/php7.0/apache2/php.ini:**

> ```
> SMTP              = localhost
> smtp_port         = 25
> mail.add_x_header = On
> ```

**/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf**

> ```
> root              = support@mydomain.ru
> mailhub           = smtp.mail.ru:465
> rewriteDomain     =
> hostname          = support@mydomain.ru
> UseSTARTTLS       = YES
> AuthUser          = support@mydomain.ru
> AuthPass          = ******
> FromLineOverride  = YES
> ```

**/etc/ssmtp/revaliases.conf**

> ```
> root:support@mydomain.ru:smtp.mail.ru:465
> localusername:support@mydomain.ru:smtp.mail.ru:465
> ```

Подскажите пожалуйста какие еще необходимо пакеты установить чтобы форма на сайте работала как раньше (использовался обычный web-хостинг, форма рабочая на .php).

Сегодня решил проверить открытые порты командой "netstat -tpln". Выдал вот что:

> ```
> Active Internet connections (only servers) 
> Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address            Foreign Address State  PID/Program name
> tcp   0      0      127.0.0.1:25             0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN 18459/sendmail: MTA 
> tcp   0      0      88.65.177.56:1500        0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN 920/ihttpd accept 
> tcp   0      0      127.0.0.1:587            0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN 18459/sendmail: MTA 
> tcp   0      0      127.0.0.1:11211          0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN 924/memcached 
> tcp   0      0      0.0.0.0:22               0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN 394/sshd    
> tcp6  0      0      :::443                   :::*            LISTEN 13738/apache2 
> tcp6  0      0      :::8080                  :::*            LISTEN 13738/apache2 
> tcp6  0      0      :::22                    :::*            LISTEN 394/sshd
> ```

Comment: Смотрите логи почты, сервера. У Вас скрипты от какого пользователя исполняются, он есть в revaliases.conf? hostname должен быть не support@mydomain.ru, а mydomain.ru. В php.ini надо указать путь до ssmtp, например sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/ssmtp -t -i. rewriteDomain тоже укажите mydomain.ru. Ну а дальше смотреть

Comment: В целом это просто форма отзыва на сайте, скрипты исполняются от всех пользователей.

Comment: добавьте в `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` строку `Debug=YES` и смотрите, что ssmtp при отправке напишет в логи (`/var/log/mail*`),

Comment: @Mimishka Я имел в виду пользователя, под которым веб сервер запущен и php скрипты выполняются.

Comment: сервер под root-запущен

Comment: сейчас стал писать что-то типа: Apr 23 15:40:02 mysite sm-mta[13540]: u3NAe2Ji013540: SYSERR(root): collect: Cannot write ./dfu3NAe2Ji013540 (bfcommit, uid=0, gid=114): No such file or directory
Apr 23 15:40:02 mysite sm-mta[13542]: u3NAe28Y013542: SYSERR(root): collect: Cannot write ./dfu3NAe28Y013542 (bfcommit, uid=0, gid=114): No such file or directory